# Django The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django

When a user registers for my app.I receive this error when he reaches the profile page.

```
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
Exception Type: ValueError 
Error during template rendering
In template C:\o\mysite\pet\templates\profile.html, error at line 6
1 <h4>My Profile</h4>
2  
3 {% if person  %}
4 <ul>           
5   <li>Name: {{ person.name }}</li>
6   <br><img src="{{ person.image.url }}">
Traceback Switch back to interactive view
File "C:\o\mysite\pet\views.py" in Profile
 71.     return render(request,'profile.html',{'board':board ,'person':person})
```

I think this error happens because my template requires a image and seen he just registered he can't add a image unless he go to the edit page and adds a page then he can access the profile page.

My profile.html

```
<h4>My Profile</h4>

{% if person  %}
<ul>           
    <li>Name: {{ person.name }}</li>
    <br><img src="{{ person.image.url }}">


</ul>
{% endif %}
```

My Profile function at views.py

```
def Profile(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))
    board = Board.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'board':board ,'person':person})
```

*I tried this solution by creating a 2 instance of Person object and separating them at my template with a if but it didn't succeed.*

```
<h4>My Profile</h4>

{% if person  %}
<ul>           
    <li>Name: {{ person.name }}</li>
 </ul>
{% endif %}
{% if bob %}
<ul>           
<br><img src="{{ bob.image.url }}">
</ul>
```

*My solutions to the Profile function*

```
def Profile(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))
    board = Board.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
    bob = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)

    return render(request,'profile.html',{'board':board ,'person':person,'bob':bob})
```

I'm been reading the documentation for Built-in template tags and filters I think a solution here is to use ( and ) template tag but I can't seem to use it properly.

How can I configure this template to make picture an option. If their are no picture leave it but display the persons name.

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`bob` and `person` are the same object,

```
person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
bob = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

So you can use just person for it.

In your template, check `image` exist or not first,

```
{% if person.image %}
    <img src="{{ person.image.url }}">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 97):

The better approach which would not violate DRY is to add a helper method to the model class like:

```
@property
def image_url(self):
    if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
        return self.image.url
```

and use default_if_none template filter to provide default url:

```
<img src="{{ object.image_url|default_if_none:'#' }}" />
```

Comment: minor remark: one can omit the `@property` altogether. `object.image_url` will work in django template without `()` either way.

Answer (score 15):

My dear friend, others solvings are good but not enough because If user hasn't profile picture you should show default image easily (not need migration). So you can follow below steps:

Add this method to your person model:

```
@property
def get_photo_url(self):
    if self.photo and hasattr(self.photo, 'url'):
        return self.photo.url
    else:
        return "/static/images/user.jpg"
```

You can use any path (/media, /static etc.) but don't forget putting default user photo as user.jpg to your path.

And change your code in template like below:

```
<img src="{{ profile.get_photo_url }}" class="img-responsive thumbnail " alt="img">
```

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly what OP was looking for, but another possible solution would be to set a default value for ImageField:

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
    # rest of the fields here
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='profile_pics/',
        default='profile_pics/default.jpg')
```

Answer (score 5):

you have two choices :

- first one:

in the model field try to put a default image value , like this :

```
PRF_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_img', blank=True, null=True , default='profile_img/925667.jpg')
```

- the second one (recommended) :

add a custom method inside your class model like the following , to return PRF_image url if exist or return empty string if not :

```
PRF_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_img', blank=True, null=True )

@property
def my_PRF_image(self):

    if self.PRF_image :
        return self.PRF_image.url
    return ''
```

and inside your template you can use :

```
{{ your_object.my_PRF_image }}
```

i hope this helpful .

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the Python 3 built-in function [**getattr**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to create your new property:

```
@property
def image_url(self):
    """
    Return self.photo.url if self.photo is not None, 
    'url' exist and has a value, else, return None.
    """
    if self.image:
        return getattr(self.photo, 'url', None)
    return None
```

and use this property in your template:

```
<img src="{{ my_obj.image_url|default_if_none:'#' }}" />
```

Comment: good answer. works in my code. no need to return `None` though as python would do that automatically

Answer (score 2):

Many way to solve this issue

Try below code

models.py # under Person class

```
@property
def imageURL(self):
    if self.image:
        return self.image.url
    else:
        return 'images/placeholder.png'
```

html file

```
<img src="{% static person.imageURL %}" class="thumbnail" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps but my database didn't save on of the pictures for the object displayed on the page.

As that object in models.py has blank=False and also I am looping through object, it constantly gave an error until I added a replacement picture in the admin for the database to render.

Answer (score 0):

This error also arises when any one or more items doesn't have an image added and the rest items do. To fix this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    pname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    img = models.ImageField(null = True,blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.pname
    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.img.url
        except:
            url=''
        return url
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem , but my issue was with the form  in HTML template. if you don't set the enctype = "multipart/form-data" attribute then it does not upload the image hence the reason for the error