# Django template ValueError The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have context information sent to this part of the view. Have a paginator and works well for pages 1-3. But going to page four it has this error.

> Exception Type: ValueError
>
> Exception Value: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.

The error in the template is highlighted by django debug as

> Error during template rendering

In template `/templates/marketplace/entry_list.html`, error at line 91:

> The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.

```
<a href="{{ e.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ e.title }}">
    {% if e.picture.url %}
        {% thumbnail e.picture "300x600" as thumb %}
            <img src="{{ thumb.url }}" alt="{{ e.title }}" />
        {% endthumbnail %}
    {% endif %}
</a>
```

The part of the view sending context info is as below

```
get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    if self.request.mobile:
        self.template_name = 'mobile/buy_n_sell.html'
    
    today = datetime.date.today()
    context = super(EntryList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['category'] = self.category
    try:
        children = self.category.get_child_categories()
    except:
        children = None
    context['child_category'] = children
    context['area'] = self.area
    return context
```

Comment: Try to change {% if e.picture.url %} to {% if e.picture %}. "url" is a read-only property which internally calls method _require_file() to check if file exists. So if file is not present, it will raise ValueError

Comment: Which is line 91 of `/templates/marketplace/entry_list.html`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322391/django-the-image-attribute-has-no-file-associated-with-it)

Answer (score 1):

use this code. maybe it will work fine for you..

```
<a href="{{ e.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ e.title }}">
{% if e.picture.url %}
    {% thumbnail e.picture "300x600" as thumb %}
        <img src="{{ e.thumb.url }}" alt="{{ e.title }}" />
    {% endthumbnail %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you explain WHY it works? I see no difference with the example in the question