# Django image attribute has no file associated with it REST API

Tags: python, django, image, rest, url

I have a model Employee with an ImageField, and I return REST API response of the model but it shows this error

```
The 'face_image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

My API generates a response this way:
https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/api.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_employee(request):
    data = [emp.as_dict() for emp in Employee.objects.all()]
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The following is the model:

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    ...
    face_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='face_image/', blank=True)

    def face_image_url(self):
        if self.face_image and hasattr(self.face_image, 'url'):
            return self.face_image.url

    def as_dict(self):
        return {"id":self.id,
                ...
                "face_image":self.face_image.url, <-- causes no file associated
                ...}
```

How do I solve this REST response handling imagefield without file ? I tried to follow some ways in here [Django The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322391/django-the-image-attribute-has-no-file-associated-with-it) but I cant accomplish with the helper function.

If I remove the imagefield, it will generate a response this way https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLjrH.jpg. But I want the imagefield to be in the structure, how to handle in this does not exist file situation

Comment: there is no serializer, you can see how the response is generated here https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/api.py

Comment: Nevermind, I did't checked the link. By the way, it's better to add the code in the answer. I dont' think that directly passing a `dict` representation to the django rest framework is good think... With a serializer, you can control how and what data is rendered (And avoiding the error you get).

Comment: ok will do that in a sec, meantime, this is how response look like if without the imagefield https://imgur.com/a/JzQrD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly handle this case. In this case, your `as_dict` method should look like:

```
def as_dict(self):
    return {"id":self.id,
            ...
            "face_image": self.face_image.url if self.face_image else None
            ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

`"face_image":self.face_image.url, <-- causes no file associated`

You don't actually use your `face_image_url` method.

It should be:

```
`"face_image":self.face_image_url()
```

As I said above, I think it's really a bad idea to handle the serialization of your model like you did. I strongly advise you to take a look at the [serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Comment: @Clément, this is the new thing, I heard about. Can you please give a doc link for this. I tried, but it is not working for me.