# Trying to save two forms, column cannot be null

Tags: python, django

I have three models bound together by foreign keys: Course > Lecture > FileUpload. I tried to create a form for Lecture model, but I actually ended up creating two forms, another one for FileUpload. And every time I try to submit the forms, I get error:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /courses/teacher/classroom/
Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'lecture_id' cannot be null")
```

The Lecture form actually submits the information, and I think that the error is related to the second form. Thing is that I want the user to be able to upload many files for the same lecture, just like in the database, and currently only one file could be uploaded which is not working.

View:

```
def classroom(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = LectureForm(request.POST)
        form2 = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            form2.save()
            return redirect('courses/courses.html')
    else:
        form1 = LectureForm()
        form2 = FileForm()
    context = {'teacher_data': TeacherData.objects.all(),
               'teachers': Teacher.objects.all(),
               'courses': Course.objects.all(),
               'form1': form1,
               'form2': form2,
               }
    return render(request, 'courses/classroom.html', context)
```

Forms:

```
class LectureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lecture
        fields = ('course', 'lecture_title', 'lecture_category', 'content')


class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileUpload
        fields = ('files',)
```

Models:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)


class Lecture(models.Model):
    LECTURE_CHOICES = (
        ('Courses', 'Courses'),
        ('Seminars', 'Seminars'),
    )
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='lectures',)
    lecture_category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LECTURE_CHOICES, default='Courses',)
    lecture_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


class FileUpload(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='documents', null=True, blank=True)
    lecture = models.ForeignKey('Lecture', related_name='files', on_delete=None, default=None)
```

Traceback: https://pastebin.com/5ViFarGP

Comment: What do you think should be filling in the `lecture` foreign key field on the `FileUpload` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error you need to pass `lecture` object to `file` before saving it to DB:

```
if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
    lecture = form1.save()
    file = form2.save(commit=False)
    file.lecture = lecture
    file.save()
```

To create multiple related object at the same time you can use [`formsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formset). In your case you need to do something like this:

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
FileFormset = inlineformset_factory(Lecture, FileUpload, fields=('files',))

if request.method == 'POST':
    form1 = LectureForm(request.POST)
    if form1.is_valid():
        lecture = form1.save()
        formset = FileFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=lecture)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

    return redirect('courses/courses.html')
else:
    form1 = LectureForm()
    formset = FileFormset()
context = {'teacher_data': TeacherData.objects.all(),
           'teachers': Teacher.objects.all(),
           'courses': Course.objects.all(),
           'form1': form1,
           'formset': formset,
           }
```

In template add inside `<form>` tag:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SEyrsMHf is this accurate? because it has no effect.

Comment: @DannM no you dont need form2 if you use formset. Check updates.

Comment: It works properly, except that now if I try to access the course to whom I added the lecture I get this: https://pastebin.com/5aF1tEEb

Comment: @DannM check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322459/641249 you need to check if files exist.

Comment: @neverwakaloner that worked. But now I notice, all files uploaded via the form, do not show...

Comment: @DannM but you can see files uploaded with formset in media directory? And new `FileUpload` instances created?

Comment: no, I can not see them there. So then I have media improperly configured ?

Comment: @DannM hm.. no, I think this mean that formset works incorrectly. Try to replace formset definition to this: `FileFormset = inlineformset_factory(Lecture, FileUpload, exclude=[])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165662/discussion-between-neverwalkaloner-and-dann-m).