# Update Form Not Submitting

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to update the fields of a model using fbv and I created different forms for those fields too. But still, I cannot submit the form no matter what. I think the problem is with image field and the form does not render to be valid. Is there a sloution for it?

models.py

```
  class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
      role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Roles)
      verified =models.BooleanField(default = False,blank=True)
      photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, default='default/testimonial2.jpg')
      slug = models.SlugField(unique=False, blank=True)

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
         super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

       def __str__(self):
          return self.user.username

       def get_absolute_url(self):
            if (self.verified==True):
               return reverse("NewApp:mail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
            else:
                return reverse("NewApp:userlist")
```

views.py

```
  def UserUpdateView(request,slug):
     object = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
     user_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=object)
     obj = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=request.user)
      profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=obj)

      if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
          user_form.save()
          profile_form.save()
          return redirect('NewApp:logindex')

       return render(request, 'NewApp/userprofile_form.html',
              {'user_form': user_form,
               'profile_form': profile_form,})
```

forms.py

```
 class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email')


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('photo',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not construct the form with `request.POST` and `request.FILES` in case of a POST request. You should implement this like:

```
def UserUpdateView(request,slug):
    user = request.user
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('NewApp:logindex')
    else:
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile) 
    return render(
        request,
        'NewApp/userprofile_form.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form,}
    )
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. But now I am getting an error "The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it." I can't even load the main page because of it.

Comment: @Srvastav4: this looks more like you did something wrong when you rendered the template, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15322391/67579

Comment: But the image is not updating. Moreover, the email is also getting removed.

Comment: @Srvastav4: did you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>`

Comment: @Srvastav4: furthermore this depends on how your `UserUpdateForm`, and `UserProfileForm` look like.

Comment: hey thank you very much. I can updatethe image now but email gets deleted.

Comment: @Srvasstav4: can you share your forms. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57164543/67579) your question.

Comment: Done. Please Have a look.

Comment: @Srvastav4: when you render the form, it does show an `email` field, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196886/discussion-between-srvastav4-and-willem-van-onsem).