# can't access image url from template, python django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, html-templates

this is the code in views.py

```
def store (request):

    products = {
       'products':product.objects.all()
    }

    return render (request, 'neizer/products.html', context = products)
```

this is the template

```
{% block content %}

<div class="products-parent">
  {%for product in products%}
  <div class="product-child">
    <img src={{product.image.url}} alt="no image available" />
    <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
    <button id="learn-more-btn">learn more</button>
    <p>${{product.price}} <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></p>
  </div>

  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I uploaded images using the /admin interface, when i access the image url in the django shell i get an actual url (which opens in the browser to the image), but when i try to access it in the template i get the above error,
the issue as it seems is with the `product.image.url`, somehow django doesn't seem to get the class instance right.
this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 828, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]

During handling of the above exception ('ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred:
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/s/webapp/main/views.py", line 20, in store
    return render (request, 'neizer/products.html', context = products)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 986, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 670, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 795, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 836, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 61, in url
    self._require_file()
  File "/mnt/s/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 38, in _require_file
    raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /store
Exception Value: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Comment: what error did you actually get?

Comment: value error, The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322391/django-the-image-attribute-has-no-file-associated-with-it)

Comment: sadly no, his problem is fixed by assigning a default image I shouldn't have to, since i do have associated image urls with each product

Comment: Where do you see this error? Can you paste the entire error trace?

Comment: Exception Type: ValueError at /store
Exception Value: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: The **entire error trace** please. Paste it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The error occure because not all of your records have an image file associated.
Most easy solution for this error is to check if there is an associated image:

```
{% if person.image %}
    <img src={{product.image.url}} />
{% else %}
    <img src="#" alt="no image available" />
{% endif %}
```

Another way is to actually have a default value for image field (default image):

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='whatever', default='your_default_image.jpg')
```

or at least put a default image in template:

```
...
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static 'your_default_img_path' %}" >
...
```

and yet another way is to user property for the model:

```
@property
def get_image_url(self):
    if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
        return self.image.url
    else:
        return "/static/images/your_default_image.jpg"
```

Comment: should fix the error for now but I can't use default images, it's supposed to be a pic of a product

Comment: i get an associated image url when i try to access it in the django shell, so there obviously is an image associated with product instance

Comment: `product.objects.all()` means that you're trying to display all existing records - are you sure all of them do have image set?

Comment: but even if there isn't an image, you wouldn't get an error, the template would just render an empty string.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'll disagree - image, if it's actually had associated file, do have `url` attribute because it's an attribute of associated file, but not a field itself. Without the file you're actually trying to get attribute of None.

Comment: i am sure every product has an image associated with them

Comment: Let's try something really simple - `Product.objects.filter(image__exact='').count()` Can you check if this return something greater then zero?

Comment: @ISAACFINKELSTEIN be sure of what you want, it won't change facts: if you get this error then some of your records don't have an image, period.

Comment: @Charnel you're right, it raises a `ValueError` if the image is not set (note it doesn't try to get `url` from `None`, that would raise an `AttributeError`, which is what confused me in the original question).

Comment: @Charnel please don't encourage hardcoding urls  - this should use the staticfiles app for computing statics urls.

Comment: I deleted all the items and re-uploaded them, now it works seems like i changed the upload to at some point and forgot to re-upload the images, thanks a lot for your help